# How to determine MIME-type of file by its content and URL via QT in Android?

Tags: android, qt, mime-types

I have an URL of file like this `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A804`. I use QMimeDatabase::mimeTypeForUrl to obtain MIME-type by content of file, but this method always return `application/octet-stream` MIME-type regardless of file content.

On iOS, the URL of file contains the `file://` scheme and this way works fine, even if the file extension is missing. Probably, because QT treats it as a [local file](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#isLocalFile), whereas the other scheme does not.

How can I determine MIME-type of file by its URL to make it work like on iOS?

Comment: Cant you query() for display name? And hence extension?

Comment: `to obtain MIME-type by content of file,` Strange approach. Do it by a query() for mime type.

Comment: @blackapps Yes, I can `query()` name, but it is assumed that files can be **without extension** and therefore it is necessary to determine MIME-type by its content. QMimeDatabase can do that, but it doesn't work for Android.

Comment: Then still you do not have to do it by content. Just query for mimetype. Even if some files are without extension you should always start for display name and extension. If you cannot determine extension then launch the other stuff.

Comment: Why are you talking about mime type by content? Do you really think that the content will be inspected the moment you ask for a mimetype?